# multiple cells in excel

Tags: excel, paste

I have an excel file like this..

```
Sr. No.     GENE ID  Gene Id (NCBI) Protein Id  Protein Sequences
1           Lmo0001  984365         NP_463534.1 
2           Lmo0002  984379         NP_463535.1 
3           Lmo0003  984420         NP_463536.1
```

This list extends to 3000 genes. I have the sequences saved in a textpad like this which are for all the 3000 genes with a space between each individual sequence.

> gi|16802049|ref|NP_463534.1| chromosomal replication initiation protein [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MQSIEDIWQETLQIVKKNMSKPSYDTWMKSTTAHSLEGNTFIISAPNNFVRDWLEKSYTQFIANILQEIT
>   GRLFDVRFIDGEQEENFEYTVIKPNPALDEDGIEIGKHMLNPRYVFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPA
>   KAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHLMHAVGHYVQQHKDNAKVMYLSSEKFTNEFISSIRDNKTEEFRTKYRNVDVL
>   LIDDIQFLAGKEGTQEEFFHTFNTLYDEQKQIIISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPPDLETR
>   IAILRKKAKADGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLVNKDITAGLAAEALKDIIPSSKS
>   QVITISGIQEAVGEYFHVRLEDFKAKKRTKSIAFPRQIAMYLSRELTDASLPKIGDEFGGRDHTTVIHAH
>   EKISQLLKTDQVLKNDLAEIEKNLRKAQNMF
>
> gi|16802050|ref|NP_463535.1| DNA polymerase III subunit beta [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MKFVIERDRLVQAVNEVTRAISARTTIPILTGIKIVVNDEGVTLTGSDSDISIEAFIPLIENDEVIVEVE
>   SFGGIVLQSKYFGDIVRRLPEENVEIEVTSNYQTNISSGQASFTLNGLDPMEYPKLPEVTDGKTIKIPIN
>   VLKNIVRQTVFAVSAIEVRPVLTGVNWIIKENKLSAVATDSHRLALREIPLETDIDEEYNIVIPGKSLSE
>   LNKLLDDASESIEMTLANNQILFKLKDLLFYSRLLEGSYPDTSRLIPTDTKSELVINSKAFLQAIDRASL
>   LARENRNNVIKLMTLENGQVEVSSNSPEVGNVSENVFSQSFTGEEIKISFNGKYMMDALRAFEGDDIQIS
>   FSGTMRPFVLRPKDAANPNEILQLITPVRTY
>
> gi|16802051|ref|NP_463536.1| hypothetical protein lmo0003 [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MMKDMTTGNPTKLIFLFAMPMLIGNLFQQFYTMIDAVIVGKFVSVDALAAVGATNSVNFFMISLIIGLMS
>   GISVVVAQYFGFKDYDRLKDVIATATYAVVFSAIILTVAGVLLAKPLLILLRTPANILDDSTIFLTTLFI
>   GILPMSLYNGMAAILRALGNSITPLIFLILSSLMNIALDFLFVVYMDMGVRGAAIATVLSQTAAAIAVIY
>   YAYRHVPFMRIERAKFKLSTPLLKEMVRIGLPSGLQGSFISIGNMALQSLINGFGSSVVAAYTAASRIDS
>   LTYQPGIAFGAASSMFAGQNIGAGKIDRVREGFWSGIKVVTAISIGITILVQLFARQFLLLFVDSSETEV
>   INIGVSYLLIVSLFYVVVGILFVVRETLRGTGDAMVPLAMGIFELVSRLVIGFVLSLYIGYVGLWWATPV
>   AWITATILGVWRYKSGAWQKKAVIRRK
>
> gi|16802052|ref|NP_463537.1| hypothetical protein lmo0004 [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MAETVKINSEFVTLGQLLQMIDVVSTGGMAKAYLSENTIYINGEQDNRRGKKLRNGDVILVPGVGKVKIE
>   QGK
>
> gi|16802053|ref|NP_463538.1| recombination protein F [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MHLESIVLRNFRNYENLELEFSPSVNVFLGENAQGKTNLLEAVLMLALAKSHRTTNDKDFIMWEKEEAKM
>   EGRIAKHGQSVPLELAITQKGKRAKVNHLEQKKLSQYVGNLNVVIFAPEDLSLVKGAPGIRRRFLNMEIG
>   QMQPIYLHNLSEYQRILQQRNQYLKMLQMKRKVDPILLDILTEQFADVAINLTKRRADFIQKLEAYAAPI
>   HHQISRGLETLKIEYKASITLNGDDPEVWKADLLQKMESIKQREIDRGVTLIGPHRDDSLFYINGQNVQD
>   FGSQGQQRTTALSIKLAEIDLIHEETGEYPVLLLDDVLSELDDYRQSHLLGAIEGKVQTFVTTTSTSGID
>   HETLKQATTFYVEKGTVKKS

Is it possible to put each sequence in each protein sequence spot on each line without having to copy and paste each manually? Any method is fine.

P.S I am sorry about the ridiculous table but without enough reputation points, I am unable to post pictures and this is the best I could manage.

@swapnil But I would like to copy the sequences from the notepad in a straight line under the protein sequences column in the first excel sheet.

Comment: Just open the text file using excel it will ask you about the delimiter specify there | and then you will get the file in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I actually edited it on textpad using regular expressions \n^[a-z] and then copied it to excel. So this is solved. Thx again. I got that advice from another stack overflow question.

Comment: I actually did this in perl later since textpad was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't be a simple copy/paste here. What I think you can do is to copy paste everything into a fresh excel sheet, and do a text to column with delimiter pipe `|` to get the last bit:

```
 chromosomal replication initiation protein [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e] MQSIEDIWQETLQIVKKNMSKPSYDTWMKSTTAHSLEGNTFIISAPNNFVRDWLEKSYTQFIANILQEIT GRLFDVRFIDGEQEENFEYTVIKPNPALDEDGIEIGKHMLNPRYVFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPA KAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHLMHAVGHYVQQHKDNAKVMYLSSEKFTNEFISSIRDNKTEEFRTKYRNVDVL LIDDIQFLAGKEGTQEEFFHTFNTLYDEQKQIIISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPPDLETR IAILRKKAKADGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLVNKDITAGLAAEALKDIIPSSKS QVITISGIQEAVGEYFHVRLEDFKAKKRTKSIAFPRQIAMYLSRELTDASLPKIGDEFGGRDHTTVIHAH EKISQLLKTDQVLKNDLAEIEKNLRKAQNMF
 DNA polymerase III subunit beta [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e] MKFVIERDRLVQAVNEVTRAISARTTIPILTGIKIVVNDEGVTLTGSDSDISIEAFIPLIENDEVIVEVE SFGGIVLQSKYFGDIVRRLPEENVEIEVTSNYQTNISSGQASFTLNGLDPMEYPKLPEVTDGKTIKIPIN VLKNIVRQTVFAVSAIEVRPVLTGVNWIIKENKLSAVATDSHRLALREIPLETDIDEEYNIVIPGKSLSE LNKLLDDASESIEMTLANNQILFKLKDLLFYSRLLEGSYPDTSRLIPTDTKSELVINSKAFLQAIDRASL LARENRNNVIKLMTLENGQVEVSSNSPEVGNVSENVFSQSFTGEEIKISFNGKYMMDALRAFEGDDIQIS FSGTMRPFVLRPKDAANPNEILQLITPVRTY
 hypothetical protein lmo0003 [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e] MMKDMTTGNPTKLIFLFAMPMLIGNLFQQFYTMIDAVIVGKFVSVDALAAVGATNSVNFFMISLIIGLMS GISVVVAQYFGFKDYDRLKDVIATATYAVVFSAIILTVAGVLLAKPLLILLRTPANILDDSTIFLTTLFI GILPMSLYNGMAAILRALGNSITPLIFLILSSLMNIALDFLFVVYMDMGVRGAAIATVLSQTAAAIAVIY YAYRHVPFMRIERAKFKLSTPLLKEMVRIGLPSGLQGSFISIGNMALQSLINGFGSSVVAAYTAASRIDS LTYQPGIAFGAASSMFAGQNIGAGKIDRVREGFWSGIKVVTAISIGITILVQLFARQFLLLFVDSSETEV INIGVSYLLIVSLFYVVVGILFVVRETLRGTGDAMVPLAMGIFELVSRLVIGFVLSLYIGYVGLWWATPV AWITATILGVWRYKSGAWQKKAVIRRK
 hypothetical protein lmo0004 [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e] MAETVKINSEFVTLGQLLQMIDVVSTGGMAKAYLSENTIYINGEQDNRRGKKLRNGDVILVPGVGKVKIE QGK
 recombination protein F [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e] MHLESIVLRNFRNYENLELEFSPSVNVFLGENAQGKTNLLEAVLMLALAKSHRTTNDKDFIMWEKEEAKM EGRIAKHGQSVPLELAITQKGKRAKVNHLEQKKLSQYVGNLNVVIFAPEDLSLVKGAPGIRRRFLNMEIG QMQPIYLHNLSEYQRILQQRNQYLKMLQMKRKVDPILLDILTEQFADVAINLTKRRADFIQKLEAYAAPI HHQISRGLETLKIEYKASITLNGDDPEVWKADLLQKMESIKQREIDRGVTLIGPHRDDSLFYINGQNVQD FGSQGQQRTTALSIKLAEIDLIHEETGEYPVLLLDDVLSELDDYRQSHLLGAIEGKVQTFVTTTSTSGID HETLKQATTFYVEKGTVKKS
```

This should go to column E. Then in column F, you can put the formula:

```
=mid(E1, find("]", E1)+2, len(E1))
```

This will extract everything after the closing square bracket `]` and thus return the sequence you need.

Let's say that these are in a sheet with name Sheet2 in the workbook of your excel file (where the first sheet contains the table you have right now).

In the first sheet, put the formula:

```
=vlookup(D2, Sheet2!D:F, 3, 0)
```

This is assuming that your text file is not in the same order as the Protein Ids listed in your table. Otherwise, you can simply copy/paste values (copy, and paste special, pick paste values) of the results of column F into the first sheet,